# CSS: display: flex and text ellipsis on the same element

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get an element with `display: flex` to work with `text-overflow: ellipsis` so overflown text is truncated with `...`. The width of the element is defined via its `flex-basis` from a parent flexbox, see here:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    abcabcabcabcabcabcabc
  </div>
</div>
```

I've search similar answers but none seem to cover this exact case. I do not want to introduce any additional elements and I want to keep the `display: flex` on the element because I need it for vertical centering.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow: _“Applies to: **block** container elements”_

Answer (score 4):

As @misorude said, `text-overflow` applies to **block** container elements.

Try the following:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    abcabcabcabcabcabcabc
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work in my case as I'd like to keep `display: flex` on the child so I can use `align-items: center` to vertically align other content like SVGs in the child.

Comment: Then you either have to add another element inside child to contain the text, or center `child` inside `parent`

Comment: Guess adding a wrapper inside `child` is the only option here. `child` is already centered in `parent`, but I specifically need to center the `child` content as well.

Comment: you don't need to add display:block .. a flex item is already a block level element